# Where should I create the composition root in a windows service?

Tags: windows-services, simple-injector, compositionroot

In the command line exe application in the windows service app that I have, there is a `main` method and that's where I'm registering all the dependencies using a simple injector `IoC`. That's my [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) now. In the same [windows service application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzk7ksy2(v=vs.110).aspx), there is a `OnStart` overridable method. That's where I'm doing an ETL operation.

Where should I keep the composition root? In the `main` method or `OnStart`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where should I keep the composition root? In the main method or OnStart?

Both are valid locations for your Composition Root. Both `Main` and your `OnStart` can be used as Composition Root. I've used both locations in the past myself. Typically, I create a separate `Bootstrapper` or `CompositionRoot` class that contains the application's Composition Root, and call that Composition Root either directly from the main, or from within my `ServiceBase` derivative.